# Adding CSS tabs to WordPress not working?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm attempting to add a series of CSS tabs to one of my wordpress pages, however it doesn't seem to be working (e.g. when I paste the following code into a wordpress page, it strips the tabs of some major components). Here's a link to what the finished tabs should look like:

**http://www.stylerepublicmagazine.com/csstabs.html**

Here's the code that I'm trying to paste to WordPress, and yes, all necessary CSS files are uploaded to my theme. Any idea why Wordpress won't display it properly?

```
<div class="tabbed-view">
  <!--tabbed 01 Starts here-->
  <form>
    <div class="tab-container grey left rounded">
      <label class="tab-label">
       <input class="tab-radio" type="radio" name="page" value="page5" checked="checked"/>
       <h2 class="tab">Interiors</h2>
       <article class="tab-page" id="page5">
       <h3>Description</h3>
       <h4>Subtitle</h4><p>Your content here</p><p> Aenean tortor mi, imperdiet id, gravida eu, posuere eu, felis. Mauris sollicitudin, turpis in hendrerit sodales, lectus ipsum pellentesque ligula, sit amet scelerisque urna nibh ut arcu. Aliquam in lacus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nulla placerat aliquam wisi.</p><p> Mauris viverra odio. Quisque fermentum pulvinar odio. Proin posuere est vitae ligula. Etiam euismod. Cras a eros.</p>
        </article>
        </label>
        <label class="tab-label">
        <input class="tab-radio" type="radio" name="page" value="page6" />
        <h2 class="tab">Bathrooms</h2>
        <article class="tab-page" id="page6">
         <h3>Stylish Bathrooms</h3>
         <h4>Subtitle</h4><p>Your content here</p>
        </article>
        </label>
        <label class="tab-label">
        <input class="tab-radio" type="radio" name="page" value="page7" />
        <h2 class="tab">Kitchen</h2>
        <article class="tab-page" id="page7">
         <h3>Modern Kitchen</h3>
         <h4>Subtitle</h4><p>Your content here</p>
        </article>
        </label>
        <label class="tab-label">
        <input class="tab-radio" type="radio" name="page" value="page8" />
        <h2 class="tab">Extra Details</h2>
        <article class="tab-page" id="page8">
         <h3>Extra Details</h3>
         <h4>Subtitle</h4><p>Your content here</p>
        </article>
        </label>
    </div>
  </form>
 </div>
 <br clear="all" /></div>
```

Comment: When you say you're pasting it into WordPress, do you mean into a WordPress page (or post), or into a file in your WordPress theme?

Comment: @Hobo I mean pasting it into a Wordpress page :)

Comment: Sorry, I should have re-read the whole question.  Is your test site public?  Are you sure the theme's queueing all the CSS (ie if you view the generated page source do you see the CSS files)? Just because it's uploaded doesn't mean it's being served.  WordPress might be adding `<br>` and `<p>` tags around your line endings - does it work if you paste all your HTML as one long line?

Comment: @Hobo Here's how it appears when I paste it in one long line: http://www.sunporchhomes.com/features-3/

Comment: Ok, my mistake on the all one line thing - I thought WordPress worked on newlines, but I guess it parses the HTML and works on tags.  If I view the source of your WordPress page, it's changing your HTML.  For example, it shows a `<p>` after each `</article>`, which your code doesn't.  I'm pretty sure one or more of its changes are messing up the sibling (`~`) selector in your CSS - if I replace the WordPress HTML with yours (in Chrome dev tools), it looks right. Are you able to change your template code?  Are you comfortable adding `remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );` for that page?

Comment: @Hobo Yes, I can edit the template file. Which file should I be editing though? E.g. In which PHP file should remove_filter exist? And I assume it would be between <?php tags, yes?

Comment: To test the theory, it should be enough to put it in your template's `functions.php`, within `<?php` / `?>` tags, yes.  Though it's likely that whole file is already within those tags.  Or there's a plugin on [this wordpress stackexchange question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6798/remove-filter-the-content-wpautop-is-not-working) that might help (not sure, I've never tried it).

Comment: @Hobo You are awesome! remove_filter worked :) Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Great news; glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You said that "all necessary CSS files are uploaded to my theme", are they linked?

If not, add to your header.php file of your wordpress theme the following line:

```
<?php if(is_page([YOUR PAGE ID])) { ?>
<link href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/[CSS FIlE Name].css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/[JAVASCRIPT FIlE Name].js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<?php } ?>
```

Replace the Page Id, CSS and Javascript with correct values.

Comment: Good thought, but it doesn't seem to be the problem here.  The CSS files in the sample page also appear in the WordPress page.  FWIW, the recommended approach would be to use `wp_register_script` and `wp_enqueue_script` (or the equivalent style functions) so WordPress can handle dependencies between files.

Comment: Any Errors/Warnings in Console?

Comment: No; the link's in the OP's comment: http://www.sunporchhomes.com/features-3/.  I'm pretty certain it's WordPress adding `<p>` and `<br>` tags - see my last comment on the question

Comment: I don't see any javascript files with the tabs functionality linked.

Comment: That's because it doesn't use javascript - it's pure CSS.  The tab names are labels for radio buttons, so when they're clicked, the selected radio button is updated.  The visible tab content depends on the radio button that's selected.  Have a look at the sample page (http://www.stylerepublicmagazine.com/csstabs.html) the OP mentioned - it's got just the basic functionality.